# Both global and local costmap empty

Tags: navigation, ros-noetic, costmap, global-costmap, local-costmap

i am trying to build a robot with navigation stack.
However, when i saw RVIZ,both local costmap and global costmap was blank. And the local costmap is not in the center of the robot.
can someone help me pls! Thank you.
This is my costmap_common_param.yaml:

```
obstacle_range: 2.5
raytrace_range: 3.0
footprint: [[-0.3, -0.2], [-0.3, 0.2], [0.3, 0.2], [0.3, -0.2]
#robot_radius: ir_of_robot
inflation_radius: 0.55
map_type: "costmap"

observation_sources: laser_scan_sensor

laser_scan_sensor: {sensor_frame: laser_frame, data_type: LaserScan, topic: scan, marking: true, clearing: true, min_obstacle_height: -1.0, max_obstacle_height: 5.0}
```

my global_costmap_params:

```
global_costmap:
  global_frame: /map
  robot_base_frame: base_link
  update_frequency: 5.0
  static_map: true
origin_x: -5
origin_y: -5
```

and my local_costmap_params:

```
  local_costmap:
   global_frame: odom
   robot_base_frame: base_link
   update_frequency: 5.0
   publish_frequency: 2.0
   static_map: false
   rolling_window: true
   width: 6.0
   height: 6.0
   resolution: 0.05
```

[image]